# How to "zero" a file with 1's

Tags: linux, bash, zero

I'll often create a file of a particular size with a trick like

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=1gb.dd bs=1M count=1024
```

or perhaps even

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=1gb.dd bs=1M count=1024
dd if=/dev/random of=1gb.dd bs=1M count=1024
```

But what if I want to get all 1's instead of 0's or random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For random data, in almost all cases use `/dev/urandom`. (You can also use `/dev/random`, but that's much much slower because it's entropy-bound. `urandom` is a PRNG which self-seeds from `random`.)

For a non-zero file, I'd suggest something like this:

```
perl -e 'print chr(0xff) x 1000' > t
```

Obviously, customise the 0xff and 1000 to taste.

Comment: `python -c "print chr(0x31)*1000" > t`  Samething only python flavored.

Answer (score 1):

This takes about four times as long as `dd if=/dev/zero`, but only slightly longer than the Perl command in **crazyscot's** answer:

```
touch shred.out; yes $'\xff' | tr -d $'\n' | shred --random-source=/dev/stdin --size=1G --iterations=1 shred.out
```

Interestingly, this similar command stopped before it got to 1 GB:

```
yes $'\xff' | tr -d $'\n' | dd if=/dev/stdin of=1gb.dd bs=1M count=1024
```

Answer (score -2):

Add another command on there after your dd.

```
sed 's/0/1/g' file.txt
```

It will replace all the 0's with 1's.

Probably a better solution out there, but that should work :-)

Edit: You'll actually have to pipe the result from that into either a new file or replace the same file. sed prints by default to the screen (IIRC)

Comment: This is wrong.  /dev/zero has all bits zero (0x00).  Your sed command is looking for the ASCII 0 digit (0x30).